# Last three values sfdc trigger functionalty

Tags: salesforce-apex

Please review the following salesforce trigger code

```
trigger BrandTrigger on Brand__c (before update) {
    for(Brand__c brand: Trigger.new){
        Brand__c oldBrand = Trigger.oldMap.get(brand.Id);
        if (oldBrand.Name != brand.Name) {

            if(String.isBlank(oldBrand.Old_Name__c)){
                brand.Old_Name__c = oldBrand.Name;
            }else{
                brand.Old_Name__c = split(oldBrand.Name + ', ' + brand.Old_Name__c );
            }
        }
    }

    private String split(String s) {
        Integer index = 0;
        for (Integer i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            index = s.indexOf(', ', index + 1);

        if(index > 2)
            return s.substring(0, index);
        else
            return s;
    }
}
```

Trigger sets at least three values ​​in the "Old Value" field. These are the historical values ​​of Brand_c.Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'll talk about the little, less important things, to eventually get to the more important ones.

**Use terniary operators** to reduce the amount of lines you have to write. The if/else clause you wrote can be done in one line:

```
brand.Old_Name__c = String.isBlank(oldBrand.Old_Name__c) ? oldBrand.Name : split(oldBrand.Name + ', ' + brand.Old_Name__c );
```

The same applies to the return statements in the split function you wrote:

```
return index > 2 ? s.substring(0, index) : s;
```

Furthermore, it is a good practice to always **place brackets in statements**, since it can be a place for bugs to hide in and it's not very noticeable:

```
for (Integer i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    index = s.indexOf(', ', index + 1);
}
```

Moreover, **don't access directly your trigger data**. It is a good practice to have them copied over to a variable so you later access them.

Lastly, as @brezotom said, you need to keep your logic out of your trigger. A best practice is to use a simple trigger framework so you have a maximum of 1 trigger per object and the actual framework decides when to run what. Here is [some docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices).

It would look something like this:

**Trigger**

```
trigger BrandTrigger on Brand__c (before insert, before update, before delete, after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {
    new BrandTriggerHandler().runHandler();
}
```

I won't implement your code with a framework since you can find a ton of examples in the web, but that's the gist - a trigger with a couple of lines that invokes your handler and then the handler manages the different events (insert, update, etc.)

Furthermore, **try to isolate business logic in business logic classes which follow the object orientation paradigm**. I'm not sure if this kind of implementation makes sense, since I don't know your use case, but something like this:

```
public class with sharing BrandSplitter {
    private Map<String, Brand__c> newBrands;
    private Map<String, Brand__c> oldBrands;

    public BrandSplitter(Map<String, Brand__c> newBrands, Map<String, Brand__c> oldBrands){
        this.newBrands = newBrands;
        this.oldBrands = oldBrands;
    }

    public List<Brand__c> splitBrands(){
        for(Brand__c newBrand: newBrands.values()){
            Brand__c oldBrand = oldBrands.get(brand.Id);
            if (oldBrand.Name != newBrand.Name) {
                newBrand.Old_Name__c = String.isBlank(oldBrand.Old_Name__c) 
                    ? oldBrand.Name 
                    : split(oldBrand.Name + ', ' + newBrand.Old_Name__c );
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You should try to keep the logic out of the trigger itself and try to put it into a handler class. This goes along with the one trigger per object pattern. What would happen if you needed to add another trigger on the same object that performed logic after update or before insert?
2. It looks like you might be replicating standard functionality with your [split function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm). Make sure the standard split method not will meet your needs.

Comment: 1. If Ineed to increase the range of this trigger, it will implement that in this way: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices

Comment: 2. Could you provide any example?